# Can I simply and efficiently check whether a Socket.io client ID is taken?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to use the client ID in Socket.io as a code for users to connect to each other's sessions by inputting it. The creator's socket id becomes the session code.

So I want to change the id to a shorter random string, and I now know how to do that, but I need to check my random string to make sure it isnt a duplicate of another connected client's id.

Yeah, I could do something like this (not tested):

```
function generate(){
    var randomStr = generateRandom(6);
    var clients = io.sockets.clients();
    var unique = true;
    for (client in clients) {
        if (clients.hasOwnProperty(client) {
           if (randomStr == client.id) unique = false;
        }
    }
    if (unique) client.id = randomStr;
    else generate();
}
```

But that requires a loop, which doesn't take advantage of a hash table the way I understand JavaScript does internally when you check for an object property, which would eliminate looping through all clients:

```
function generate(){
    var randomStr = generateRandom(6);
    var clients = io.sockets.clients();
    if (!clients[randomStr]) client.id = randomStr;
    else generate();
}
```

Is there some way to efficiently check clients for an existing ID in a way similar to this?

I could apply the ID's to an object as I convert client ID's when they connect, but I wanted to make sure there isnt a simple way to check efficiently without adding more code (updating the object each time a client connects).

Comment: Your second `generate` method should do the trick just fine.

Comment: @nem Really?? I didn't realize the object was keyed by IDs, ok well great. Should I delete this?

Comment: Sorry, I was editing your code that was incomplete, now I realize that was intended. Check out **@DanielKobe's** answer then, it seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In socket io ≥ 1.0 you can use `io.sockets.connected[socketid]`. You can use this to update your generate function.

```
function generate(client_to_update){
    var randomStr = generateRandom(6);
    var client = io.sockets.connected[randomStr];
    if (!client) client_to_update.id = randomStr;
    else generate(client_to_update);
}
```